# How to connect Laravel with remote PostgreSQL Database with ssh tunnelling?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

How to connect Laravel with remote PostgreSQL Database with ssh tunnelling?

Is there any laravel package that can help to make connection with database detail and ssh detail

Comment: Take a look of this package https://phpseclib.com/docs/why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Laravel can be used with PostgreSQL via SSH Tunneling. This can be done by using "phpseclib" library, documentation [here](https://phpseclib.com/docs/why) and GitHub [here](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib).

### Steps:

1. After installing & setting up you need to create a new SSH connection by providing hostname, username and password.
2. Create new tunnel for the database by providing hostname & port number. Also provide local port number to access database.
3. Update connection settings in Laravel configuration file by specifying the local port number.

Don't forget to keep tunnel open in background.